# SSL with wildfly and apache

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4

I'm using wildfly with apache (mod_jk). HTTP connection works fine, but now I want to use HTTPS. Is it enough to configure apache virtualhost that would be listening on https port + set up certificate there? Or do I have to set up SSL listeners in both wildfly and apache (and should it be the same certificate if so)?

Comment: "I" is always uppercase on English.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up SSL/TLS in apache is enough!